# Is it possible to use route.meta property outside of the component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using Vue 3 in my project and I used route.meta property inside the Vue component but when I moved that into .ts file it doesn't work anymore and in-browser appeared an error.

My .ts file:

```js
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import { computed } from "vue";

const route = useRoute();

export const myfunction = computed(() => {
  return route.meta.somedata;
});
```

Error from the browser:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined
```

The same code works fine in .vue files.
Is there any way to use meta property outside of the .vue file?

Comment: If you have defined the router separately in a file, then you can directly import the router from that file and use that.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari yes I have router/index.ts file  I already tried to import it but it will be imported as a router, not the route that router import doesn't have meta property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, firstly need to import the router file.

```js
import router from "@/router/index";
```

Then using the router object we can get currentRoute.value and then access meta properties.

```js
router.currentRoute.value.meta.someData
```

The final code should look like this:

```js
import { computed } from "vue";
import router from "@/router/index";

export const myfunction = computed(() => {
  return router.currentRoute.value.meta.someData;
});
```